# What is 'salt' in graphite?

Tags: graphite

```
http://thisthatserver/render/?width=586&height=308&_salt=1385043488.854&target=carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.metricsReceived
```

&_salt=1385043488.854

and

```
http://thisthatserver/render/?width=586&height=308&_salt=1385043505.897&target=carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-111-a.metricsReceived&areaMode=all
```

&_salt=1385043505.897

What is this salt parameter? i have noticed it since i upgraded to v0.9.12

Comment: Ignore the - 'graphite.com' the setup is on my local subnet. Graphite is a rrd-django based graphing tool.

Comment: Maybe this ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Comment: Incidentally, `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1385043488.854) = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 21, 14, 18, 8, 854000)`, and Django seems to be using times to validate its cookies (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/), so it is most probably a security thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It looks like it](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/master/webapp/content/js/composer.js#L110) is a ["cache buster"](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/).  So "salt" is a bit of a misnomer -IMO-, as it is usually used in a cryptographic context.

In this case, the "salt" (i.e. cache buster) prevents the browser (or a proxy) from caching the graph/data, because the URL is always unique.  Because of this we can be sure that the browser/proxy is always requesting graphs of the server (*at the cost of additional round trips when perhaps the aren't needed -because the data may not have changed-*).